# PHP/MYSQL Update only first row with defined value

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I want to update my database using constraints

```
for ($count = 0; $count <= $size; $count++) {
if($dayOfTheWeek[$count] == "Friday" or $dayOfTheWeek[$count] == "Saturday"){

$query = "UPDATE rota SET title='Guest' WHERE date = '$dateMonthYearArr[$count]' AND starttime = '22:00'";               
$dayresult = mysql_query($query);}
}
```

I have multiple users with a `$starttime` of 22:00, but i only want the first users detail to be updated leaving the rest unchanged. how would i go about doing this?

Comment: ...appending `LIMIT 1` :-)? but I smell fishy database design... at least also use a `ORDER BY` clause, so your result will be defined

Comment: mysql is deprecated as of 5.5 and you can use mysqli_* since 5.3 I would advise moving to that, wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want one record to be changed you can append this to the end of your statement:

```
LIMIT 1
```

For example:

```
$query = "UPDATE rota SET title='Guest' WHERE date = '$dateMonthYearArr[$count]' AND starttime = '22:00' LIMIT 1";
```